# Richfaces popup panel not working

Tags: java, popup, richfaces, popuppanel, richfaces-modal

Whenever error is coming in Java code, I am redirecting my page to error page. Please find below my code. but nothing is coming in my IE.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<head>
</head>                
<body>                  
<div style="width:700px; text-align:center;">
                <span style="font-size: 12pt; font-face: bold; color: red">
                                Refund initiate failed! Please contact the help desk for assistance.
                </span>

<rich:popupPanel id="messagePanel" modal="true" autosized="true" resizeable="false"
                                  >
                                  <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                                               Refund initiate failed! Please contact the help desk for assistance.
                                  </h:panelGrid>                           
                                  <center>      
                                  <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                                         <h:commandButton immediate="true" value="close"
                                                onclick="#{rich:component('messagePanel')}.hide(); return false;"/>                            

                                  </h:panelGrid>       
                                  </center>
                       </rich:popupPanel>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: Popup panel is not coming. simply empty page only displaying

Answer (score 0):

`<rich:popupPanel>` is hidden by default, to make it show use `show="true"`. Read the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/rich/popupPanel.html).

EDIT:

Your page isn't well formed, use `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` so that the resources (CSS and JS) will be imported.

Comment: I've edited the answer, if it still isn't working check the generated HTML.